# how to add index in mysql sum select

Tags: mysql, indexing

for one sql example,

```
       "select sum(a), sum(b) from c"
```

how to add index for this table to improve query efficiency.
I have tried

```
        "alter table c add index `select`(`a`,`b`)"
```

but it seemingly ineffective

Comment: An index is not going to help this query, unless table `c` has very large records.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL `SELECT SUM(a), SUM(b) FROM c` will do a full table scan. Indexes can't be used unless you have a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes,I have a WHERE clause,like this                                         SELECT SUM(a), SUM(b), FROM c WHERE d in (....) GROUP BY d ,f;              and  table c has very large records

Comment: Then your index (`a`,`b,`) won't help.  index_name(`d`) will help.  It depends on your where clause or "order by" clause, not the columns you selected.